# How to read and process millions of XML file and process only those XML files which are modified

Tags: c++

I have attended one interview where the interviewer asked me that, in a directory millions of XML files are there . I need to read those files and process it in efficient way.

Constraint 1:  Everyday I have to read only modified XML files only.

Constraint 2:  you will not get to know the last modified date and time.

I told him that we can read all XML files to some data structure as it will be faster to read data structure than file reading every-time. And compare everyday by reading XML file contents, if any modified file content files found then process only those files.

But he told me, reading all file contents into memory increases the memory .

So what should be the best approach for the above ?Can someone help me ?

Comment: In Windows you can use the [archive bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archive_bit).

Comment: Create a checksum for each file. Process only those files for which the checksum has changed.

Comment: Use inotify (on Linux) or similar notification mechanisms on other operating systems?

Comment: Record all the last modified dates each time a file is checked? Or is that what you are saying you can't do?

Comment: Notify and last modified dates and time also not available.